# FLV player/converter for Fedora

Tags: fedora, media-player, vlc-media-player, video-conversion

Please suggest me flv player for Fedora 9. Also if flv to mp4 converter so  that I can play with MPlayer. I am not able to run vlc player. I installed VLC through yum install player. Now in applications menu, it shows VLC player, but when I click it, nothing happens. Any solution?

Also when I plug my earpieces into the socket, the sound output still comes on speakers, means I can listen on both earpieces and speakers. Please help. I have Fedora 9 on Sony Vaio. It works well on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If vlc won't run it isn't installed properly.  I would use ffmpeg.  You can compile it from source and it handles an ungodly amount of codecs(including flv containers).  Mplayer has a version of ffmpeg in it's source tree without many dependencies.  If you can't get ffmpeg from svn to compile try mplayer from source.  Alternately, if you just need one file converted let me know and I'll do it for you.

Comment: ffmpeg is for flv files? I need many files to be converted. Please tell me the converter.

Comment: Okay I am doing svn check out of ffmpeg. I would update again if I face any problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: not a problem: this will give you a basic idea http://www.ubuntugeek.com/convert-flv-google-videos-to-mpg-using-ffmpeg.html, but there is a LOT you can do with ffmpeg for encoding/decoding/transcoding...It's actually the video backend for a lot of products(see the hall of shame wiki at ffmpeg.org)

Comment: did this work for you? if not let me know...if yes can i get the check